# divide two factorials by using a recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, division, factorial

I wrote a simple recursive function that calculates factorials. But in my problem what I want to do is int result = n!/k!. When I change the result to double instead of int I get the error : Exception in thread “main” java.lang.StackOverflowError
, and even if the function returns double it won't return the correct result. For example I have this function

```
 static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

and I want to do factorial(2)/factorial(3) so it returns 1/3

Comment: There isn't factorial for double!

Comment: There is no recursion here and your loop will stop at the first iteration because you have a `return` statement in it.

Comment: You can cast the result to double: `double x = (double)factorial(2) / factorial(3);`

Comment: @Titus It looks that way because of poor indentation, but the `return` is outside the loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Oh, yes, you're right, the loop's body is not delimited by `{}`.

Comment: As mentioned, there is no recursion here. Also, this code would not produce a stack overflow. Show the actual code that is causing the error. Also, [learn how to format your question properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Ok, you've updated with a recursive function. But I still don't see a problem. It works [here](https://ideone.com/AIITNw). This code could cause a stack overflow if you pass a negative number. Is that what you are doing? Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you for your reply. I cast the result and it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is correct you might not have done casting of `int` to `double` which might be the problem. Here is the function which will recursively multiply a higher number `n` upto a lower number `k` where both `n and k` are **Natural Numbers**.

```
static int factorial(int n,int end){
    if(n == end){
        return end;
    }else{
        return n * factorial(n-1,end);
    }
}
```

If you need the factorial of a number, pass `1` into the second argument.

Also, if you do not need the factorials of ***n*** and ***k*** you can optimize your code. As you know while dividing for example `6!` by `4!` result will be `6x5`. So, by optimizing your code I have come up with the solution below. This will give two values `numerator` and `denominator`. You can easily do what you want with it in more faster way than calculating both factorials and dividing them again.

```
if(n == k){
    numerator = 1;
    denominator = 1;
}else if(n > k){
    numerator = factorial(n,k+1);
    denominator = 1;
}else{
    numerator = 1;
    denominator = factorial(k,n+1);
}
```

I hope this helps.